# Why do boxers/fighters oftentimes spin around each other in the ring?

Tags: boxing, mma, wrestling, martial-arts

Boxing, MMA, wrestling, etc. - in many different types of 1v1 matches, many fighters will sort of 'orbit' around each other throughout the match regardless of fighting type.

Why do fighters do this? Is there some sort of advantage to this 'orbit-movement' during matches? Is clock-wise spinning and counter-clock-wise spinning different?

Answer (score 1):

There are numerous reasons for this orbiting movement around the ring seen in all types of fighting matches. First, fighters wish to move since being a mobile target often has the benefit of being harder to hit. Bear in mind that fighters wish to also control the ring and their opponents through this spinning in question. Whether the spinning occurs clock-wise or counter-wise is important, because it affects the fighters location in relation to the ring's boundaries; they can be outmaneuvered or pinned into the corners or perimeters. Moreover due to the fighter's chosen stance at any given moment, a clock-wise or counter-wise turn may make different openings (zones of the body) available to the fighters in order to take advantage and defeat their opponents.